# overflow:hidden in div not working

Tags: html, css

I need my elements to show in a single line and be hidden on overflow, but my current code breaks the line if the screen is too short in width. How do I make the elements  hidden on overflow when screen width is short?

https://jsfiddle.net/4szyqv20/5/

```
<html><body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="element">
    1000000
    </div>
    <div class="element">
    1000001
    </div>
        <div class="element">
    1000002
    </div>
        <div class="element">
    1000003
    </div>
        <div class="element">
    1000004
    </div>
        <div class="element">
    1000005
    </div>
        <div class="element">
    1000006
    </div>
        <div class="element">
    1000007
    </div>
</div>

</body></html>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: block
  overflow: hidden;
}
.element {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow: hidden` will not do anything if the container doesn't have a fixed size. You'll also need to add `white-space: nowrap` in order to prevent text-wrapping.

Your CSS will look something like this:

```
.container {
    display: block
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.element {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid black 1px;
}
```

[Here is an updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/4szyqv20/17/)

Comment: `no-wrap` is not a valid value for `white-space`.

Comment: yes pay attention to typo especially for value ... and your code will look something like --->it's like his code you did nothing

Comment: Very sorry, I fixed all of the issues.

Answer (score 2):

On `.container` you want to add `white-space: nowrap;`